# not responding or hang in excel macro 2010

Tags: excel, vba

help,  I have this code in excel macro. And I encounter hang when i execute the excel program it runs perfect in excel 2000 but error in excel 2010. thanks in advance...

```
Sub AddReference()
Macro purpose:  To add a reference to the project using the GUID for the`
     'reference library     
    Dim strGUID As String, theRef As Variant, i As Long     
     'Update the GUID you need below.
    strGUID = "{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"     
     'Set to continue in case of error
    On Error Resume Next     
     'Remove any missing references    
    For i = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Count To 1 Step -1     
        Set theRef = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Item(i)        
        If theRef.isbroken = True Then        
            ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.Remove theRef
        End If         
    Next i     
     'Clear any errors so that error trapping for GUID additions can be evaluated
    Err.Clear     
     'Add the reference
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid _
    GUID:=strGUID, Major:=1, Minor:=0     
     'If an error was encountered, inform the user
    Select Case Err.Number
    Case Is = 32813
         'Reference already in use.  No action necessary
    Case Is = vbNullString
         'Reference added without issue
    Case Else
         'An unknown error was encountered, so alert the user
        MsgBox "A problem was encountered trying to" & vbNewLine _
        & "add or remove a reference in this file" & vbNewLine & "Please check the " _
        & "references in your VBA project!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error!"
    End Select
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide more information than a simple "error in excel 2010". Which error was thrown? Have you tested the GUID, major and minor version are still valid after recent update?

Comment: And, if my memory serves me right, nothing in a vba project could possibly be ran if there is a `MISSING` reference. As the entire project will fail to compile.

Comment: Yes, the entire project will not compile with a missing reference although Excel I *think* will allow execution up until the procedure which relies on that reference.  My first guess is also that the GUID is no longer valid -- especially from Excel 2000 --> 2010 that seems likely.

Comment: tnx for the reply the error in excel is in the title

Comment: i think doevents will do but i'm not that sure where to put cause it still hang

Comment: This code works for me, in Excel 2010, Windows 7.  although I do not understand why you would need to add a reference to the *Microsoft Excel 14.0 Object Library*.

Answer (score 0):

This GUID refers to **Primary Interop Assemblies", it's the same GUID for all office versions (2003, 2007, 2010 that I can confirm).

I guess your computer does not have the it/proper version installed.

You need to install it for Office 2010. [Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

Let us know if you have more than 1 version of Office installed on your computer.

You most likely need to change in your code:

`Major:=1, Minor:=0` (office 2003) to `Major:=1, Minor:=7` (office 2010)